# How to optimize handling `bytea` in Postgres

Tags: database, postgresql, database-performance, bitcoin, cryptocurrency

I'm working on a [Bitcoin Indexer](https://github.com/dpc/rust-bitcoin-indexer) that dumps blockchain data into Postgres.

I had a previous DB schema design that used `SERIAL` IDs, but I'm now playing with db schema in which primary keys/IDs are using `BYTEA` type. It's much heavier approach for the db, but it makes a lot of higher-level things easier, since IDs in the DB are the same as globally unique cryptographic IDs used on the blockchain (kind of - I truncate 32bytes to just 16B, since I think it is unique enough). Anyway...

I'm looking for ways to optimize the performance. Especially `INSERT` operations.

First: is `bytea` even the best type for a fixed size byte array?

Second: Is there a better syntax for `INSERT`ing multiple values than this:

```
INSERT INTO block_tx(block_hash_id, tx_hash_id)VALUES(\'\\x5a88c1899a84b8292d35c735f5683dcd\'::bytea,\'\\x5b8428f57026e69b1d51aaafdf8cf669\'::bytea),(\'\\x5a88c1899a84b8292d35c735f5683dcd\'::bytea,\'\\xacfcbab38dc315adb698653d3429f449\'::bytea),(\'\\x4357082b70a8371437b6806cdf6202ce\'::bytea,\'\\x65e1bd91f04ff6fd92df70b6ab2ee455\'::bytea),(\'\\x4357082b70a8371437b6806cdf6202ce\'::bytea,\'\\x2970c8f15ac24141cd070c2b3155f257\'::bytea),(\'\\x4357082b70a8371437b6806cdf6202ce\'::bytea,\'\\x7a71cbdf9f1d9e7c2a4ad6aff7b82345\'::bytea),
```

As you can see this `::bytea` suffix keeps repeating needlessly. I use multi-value inserts, and I batch a lot of inserts into huge transactions. It is known to improve performance, and worked well in my previous design where I wasn't using `BYTEA` everywhere.

Third: Since I use `BYTEA` (sometimes multiple of them) as keys/indices - it looks like the indices got much heavier to update now when inserting. Anything that I can do about it?

Any other ideas are welcome. I did a lot of research on general optimization of `INSERT`ing a massive amount of data - it's mostly the `BYTEA` type aspect that I'm unfamiliar with.

Comment: What client-side drivers/languages are you targeting? Some can use COPY and/or binary bind parameters which would cut by half the data to transmit.

Comment: I'm using Rust's `postres` crate. Also, since `COPY` "moves data between PostgreSQL tables and standard file-system files, it is not really something I want to use anyway.

A binary encoding of queries might be an option, but I don't think this crate exposes the necessary API.

Comment: Can't help with Rust but COPY FROM STDIN copies data fed to the network connection without involving files, and is the primary way to do fast imports.

Answer (score -1):

How many rows do you have?  How big is the table?  How much RAM do you have?

I would guess that the table is much bigger than will fit in RAM.  The randomness of the `PRIMARY KEY` leads to each `INSERT` landing in 'random' places in the table -- often not cached.  As the table gets bigger and bigger, the problem will get worse and worse.

Ultimately, the cache will be useless, and each `INSERT` will require a disk hit.  That is, your processing will slow to disk speed.

What to do?  Get more RAM than the table size.  Get faster disks.

(Meanwhile, shrinking to 16 bytes instead of 32 is probably not worth the effort.)

You can get a *slight* improvement by gathering lots of rows, sorting them, *then* inserting them in a big batch.  This gives you a *slightly* better chance of making use of the cache.

Comment: > 1 billion of entries. I have 32GB of memory. I don't think it will be ever feasible for me to fit this all in memory. :)

I am aware that inserting is slow now. It's OK since blockchains are generally slow. But on my slowass SMR disk drive it was impossible to work on this db. On my 4 * NVME btrfs it is actually quite snappy.

Comment: What are the indexes on the table?